# Simplify seems to give wrong result

Tags: simplifying-expressions, precision-and-accuracy

I have an very long expression named "Bug", which is made by different precision numbers. When I directly apply Simplify, it seems to give me a wrong result. However when I apply SetPrecision to set the precision to 16, it seems works. Also, it seems works for Expand and N. So is it a bug when dealing with long expressions with different precision components with Simplify?

Here is a demonstration of the problem: (Sorry for not putting the expressions directly in here, cause its too long)

```
Bug = CloudGet[
  CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/9e306071-0031-4422-9638-53912405789c"]
]    

Bug // N // Simplify
(* 0.0000620417 + 0.0000316605 b1 - 53.7477 b2 - 245.021 b3 - 69.4272 b4 *)

SetPrecision[Bug, 16] // Simplify
(* 0.0000620417319769112 + 0.0000316605223880081 b1 - 
 53.7476717448279 b2 - 245.020938464761 b3 - 69.4272142674867 b4 *)

Bug // Expand
(* 0.00006204173198 + 0.00003166052239 b1 - 
 53.7476717448279 b2 - 245.020938464761 b3 - 69.427214267487 b4 *)

Bug // Simplify
(* 0.*10^-22 + 0.00003166052238800815 b1 - 53.7476717448279 b2 - 
 245.0209384647608 b3 - 69.4272142674867 b4 *)
```

Comment: what happens if you increase the precision parameter in `SetPrecision` ? Do you observe a convergence ? (you could have copy paste your code here)

Comment: @Smilia Thank you for your comment. Yes, I do find a convergence when i increased the precision parameter in SetPrecision to 17, 18, 19, ... The result remains the same (it didn't display more digits). And the expression for "Bug" in my code is too long to put it here, i don't how to upload mfiles.

Comment: @EDMHormPhys If you cannot reduce the size of `Bug` enough to post it here (please try to do this first), you can use `CloudPut[Bug]` to upload the expression to the Wolfram Cloud. Others can then download it again using `CloudGet[CloudObject[...]]`, where `CloudObject[...]` is the expression returned by `CloudPut`

Comment: @LukasLang，Thank you for your advices. I tried my best to reduce the size of it, and it is still too long to put it here. So i tried ur second advice, here is it: CloudGet[
CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/dadf2fe9-ceb5-4948-9d17-\
80af91677d2e"]].

Comment: @EDMHormPhys Sorry, it looks like I have made a mistake with the `CloudPut` command: It should be `CloudPut[Bug, Permissions->"Public"]`, otherwise others can't access it. Can you execute the fixed code and put the resulting `CloudObject` into the question? Alternatively, `CloudPublish@CloudPut[Bug]` should also work

Comment: @LukasLang, thank you for ur reminder, i updated it.

Comment: It does seem to be less than desirable behavior. I do not know if it is a bug, or a consequence of the symbolic transformations done by `Simplify` not playing nice with approximate numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment - that being said, one of the problems appears to be a spurious loss of precision when using `Simplify`. Consider the following example (`expr` below is a slightly modified version of parts of `Bug` from the question)

```
expr = -0.57553772946734996286675776331986281009`15.954589770191005 \
(-0.2`99.782317 - 13.2`99.6264193371874 b3 - 
     45.73333333`99.86504826696864 b4);

showPrec[expr_] := 
 Map[Labeled[N@#, Style[Precision@#, Gray]] &, expr, {-1}]

showPrec@expr

showPrec@Simplify@expr

showPrec@Expand@expr
```

[image]

The gray numbers below the expression indicate the precision of the terms. Note how the precision of the second term is slightly lower when using `Simplify` as opposed to `Expand`. Interestingly, `Simplify[expr, TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,#&}]` does not show the same loss of precision. Unfortunately, this does not help in the original case, so something more must be going on.